# Why doesn't my song work in my android app?

Tags: java, android

My audio doesn't play.
What is the problem ??

```
public class AudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(AudioActivity.this, R.raw.boot);
        Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //mp = MediaPlayer.create(AudioActivity.this, R.raw.boot);
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        Button bause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bause);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //mp = MediaPlayer.create(AudioActivity.this, R.raw.boot);
                mp.pause();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called `setOnClickListener()` on the play button twice. You meant to call `bause.setOnClickListener()`. When you hit the play button, instead it is pausing.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting OnClickListener of play button twice. 
So when you click the play button it will pause the media player instead of playing it.

change it to following:

```
Button bause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bause);
        bause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //mp = MediaPlayer.create(AudioActivity.this, R.raw.boot);
                mp.pause();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

This has to do with method scopes. You're creating the `MediaPlayer` instance inside the `onCreate` method. When that method ends, the `mp` variable goes away as well since it was created in the method's scope. When the `onClickListener` is executed, the variable doesn't exist anymore. Move the variable declaration to the class' scope, so that it remains available for the lifetime of the class. Something like:

```
public class AudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private MediaPlayer mp;

  //...

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(AudioActivity.this, R.raw.boot);

    //...
  }
```

Comment: -1 `mp` was declared `final`, so the reference was never lost. In Java, as long as you have a reference to an object, that object must still exist.

Comment: Eh, completely disregarded the `final` keyword when answering. Just saw the declaration inside the method. My bad.